# Multiple Facebook Comments Instances

Tags: jquery, facebook, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml

I need to load several Facebook Comments boxes on a page whenever a user performs a certain action using JQuery. (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

I've gotten it to work if I were to load all the comment fields at once, but this is bad programming practice.

When I attempt to load the comments sequentially, the first comment appears but all subsequent ones fail to load.

I've created a testing script to demonstrate.

Page 1:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'></script>

  <div id='A' align='center' onclick='clickA();'><strong>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</strong></div>
  <div id='B' align='center' onclick='clickB();'><strong>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</strong></div>
  <div id='C' align='center' onclick='clickC();'><strong>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</strong></div>
  <div id='ALL' align='center' onclick='load_all();'><strong>Load ALL</strong></div>

<script>

var facebook_comments_page = 'http://localhost/test2.html';

function clickA(){ 
    $('#A').load( facebook_comments_page);
}

function clickB(){
    $('#B').load(facebook_comments_page);
}

function clickC(){
    $('#A').empty();//not working to remove the dom
    $('#A').detach();//not working to remove the dom
    $('#A').remove();//not working to remove the dom

    $('#C').load(facebook_comments_page );
}

function load_all(){  
  $('#A').load(facebook_comments_page);
  $('#B').load(facebook_comments_page);
  $('#C').load(facebook_comments_page);
}

</script>
```

Page 2 - the actual Facebook Comments Page (test2.html):

```
<script class='fb-comments'>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


    <div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://example.com' data-num-posts='2' data-width='470' ></div>
```

In this example, if you initially press  AAAA, BBBB, or CCCC the Facebook comments page loads. But if you press any of the remaining ones, they do not load. However, if you first  select Load ALL, then all three load.

With CCC, I thought that if destroy the contents of AAA, then CCC would load. However, it does not. I think somehow JQuery is killing the script contents on subsequent calls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Chris, personally i avoid jQuery when possible.  Here is a stand alone sample that will do the same as your doing, with out jQuery.

1. javascript sdk loads asynchronously, upon completion and initialization a button will be drawn to each div to load that comment box.
2. pressing button will load html5 div into div's and xfbml will parse.

---

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="cA"></div>
    <div id="cB"></div>
    <div id="cC"></div>
    <div id="cAll"></div>
    <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
        appId  : 'App_ID_HERE',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
        //channelUrl : 'https://anotherfeed.com/emo/channel.html', // channel.html file
        oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
            });
document.getElementById('cA').innerHTML='<button onclick="commentA();">Load A</button>';
document.getElementById('cB').innerHTML='<button onclick="commentB();">Load B</button>';
document.getElementById('cC').innerHTML='<button onclick="commentC();">Load C</button>';
document.getElementById('cAll').innerHTML='<button onclick="commentA();commentB();commentC();">Load All</button>';
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      // Add your application id where says App_ID_HERE
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=App_ID_HERE";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function commentA(){
    var cb=document.getElementById('cA');
   cb.innerHTML='<div class=\'fb-comments\' data-href=\'http://example.com?page=1\' data-num-posts=\'2\' data-width=\'470\'></div>';
    FB.XFBML.parse(cb);
    };
    function commentB(){
    var cb=document.getElementById('cB');
    cb.innerHTML='<div class=\'fb-comments\' data-href=\'http://example.com?page=2\' data-num-posts=\'2\' data-width=\'470\'></div>';
    FB.XFBML.parse(cb);
    };
    function commentC(){
    var cb=document.getElementById('cC');
    cb.innerHTML='<div class=\'fb-comments\' data-href=\'http://example.com?page=3\' data-num-posts=\'2\' data-width=\'470\'></div>';
    FB.XFBML.parse(cb);
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: I couldn't get your script to run, even after inserting my App ID. Nothing happened.