# Facebook Comments into ajax loaded jQuery-ui accordion, load OK only on first ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, accordion, facebook-comments

1. I have a function that load a jquery ui accordion (differents accordions based on different id)
2. When I click on the tab titled "Facebook Comments" I do:

   ```
   $("#myaccordion").bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
       id = $("#myaccordion").data('id');
       switch (ui.newHeader.text()) {
           case "Facebook Comments":
               displayFb(id);
               break;
       }
   });
   ```
3. The "displayFB" function is:

   ```
   function displayFb(id){
       $.get('/fbcomments/' + id, function(data) {
           $("#facecomm").append(data);
           });
       }
   ```

   Where www.myweb.com/fbcomments/id is:

   ```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo '/fbcomments/'.$id ?>" data-num-posts="10" data-width="220"></div>
   ```
4. When I load the homepage, then choose an accordion, then open a Facebook Comments, it works perfect. If I reload the page and choose another accordion, work perfect again. **The problem is when I choose another accordion or the same again without reload the whole page. The accordions loads very well, all the data on them (some tabs of images, text, videos, etc), but the facebook comments don't appear.**
5. I tried:

   - loading the `#fb-root` and facebook comment `<script>` on the main layout....doesn't work.
   - adding `FB.XFBML.parse();` into displayFB function....doesn't work
   - adding `FB.XFBML.parse();` into a `$(document).ready(function(){}` ...doesn't work.
6. Thank you for reading and try to help!!

***UPDATE:***

7. I made this little demo...I can't make it work...maybe jsfiddle is not the best place to insert Facebook Comments: [My First Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaFwt/2/)
8. Maybe is important to say that I use cakephp on my site...
9. Please remember that my code works perfect at first accordion call and displayFb function...then when I change to other accordion...it crash...
10. Thank you again!!

***UPDATE2:***

11. [This is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997091/multiple-facebook-comments-instances) of a user....very similar to mine. Please see that his doesn't use an accordion...but jquery in common....maybe somebody could understand better than me the answer...

Comment: try console.log(data) in displayFb function and check is it returning the data from api?

Comment: I tried, it return data every time...it's working ok but don't show the comments, only the first time. Thank you.

Comment: can you prepare a demo and provide any link so I can understand where should be the problem.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your help. I will prepare a demo ASAP to show more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where www.myweb.com/fbcomments/id is:

So you’re effectively adding the DIV element `#fb-root` and loading the JS SDK over and over again and place it inside your document … which is not a good idea.

Try loading *only* the `.fb-comments` element via AJAX, and run `FB.XFBML.parse` on that new piece of content afterwards.

Embed `#fb-root` and the JS SDK in your page from the beginning, and *only once*.

Comment: I tried. If I load the facebook comment <script> in main layout (and the .fb-comments via ajax)....doesn't work. But if I prepend the #fb-root and the facebook <script> on the <body> tag, when I run displayFb function, It works. But I still have problems on second accordion load. Each time I click on new accordion, the prepended element #fb-root load without his content (severals divs and iframes with scripts...), even If I remove() the #fb-root...

Comment: Maybe I don't understand at all the main concepts, and maybe what I will say is a madness...but I think that the facebook <script> tag if is runned once, no matter if is ajax loaded or not, I cannot call it again and insert the proper content on #fb-root and .fb-comments ...there is some way to force to "free" the memory and run again the facebook script?

Comment: You should not insert anything into `#fb-root` yourself, leave that element alone. Load your dynamic content including the `.fb-comments` element and place it in the document – and then tell the FB script, that it has to run the XFBML parser again on this new part of the document.

Comment: OMG!! is working!! well....not 100% perfect but works....Finally, I add the FB.XFBML.parse() INTO the ajax called code....not on the main layout or the accordion....

Comment: I can't solve how to not load the #fb-root over and over again...so the facebook loader icon stay on top of the iframe....I don't know why it's work but the loader still there...afterall, **really thank you for your help, CBroe and all you guys....and forgive me for don't try this solution before...right now is very obvious to me...**

Comment: Finally It was there the solution...I take the #fb-root and fb script and embed just after the accordion container div...Also, on the page loaded by ajax (/fbcomments/' + id) I put after the .fb-comments div, the FB.XFBML.parse() function...THANK YOU!! works perfect...

Answer (score 0):

You could use your browsers debugger or fiddler to analyse the response from the server. It may well contain an error that you are not seeing because your Ajax call doesn't handle errors.

Instead of Using $.get() try using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and provide a error() callback function to see what any error might be coming back from your Ajax call. Something like this. (not tested)

You may need to set the datatype:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/fbcomments/"+id,
      success: function (response) {
        // Append the data here into the dom
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I did what you say...change the method and error function....It have the same behaviour of my solution: load the comments only on first accordion chosen (any of them)...and then when I pick another accordion, dissapear and no more load...

Comment: A weird thing: when I tried console.log to response(data), it show all the content loaded from www.myweb.com/fbcomments/id ....it's look ok but don't load the iframe of the fbcomments. I think that the solution is on FB.XFBML.parse(); but how? I tried too....again with bad results...

Comment: 1) Debug the displayfb() code and check that when you append the response into #facecomm, that the Dom is changed and the new elements are present, perhaps they are hidden. 2) Try to move the facecomm element so that it is not in an Iframe just to test if this is what is causing the issue. 3). I agree with the other comments. A cutdown demo will help us help you. A really good way to do this is to use http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: Is displayfb() running in the context of the I frame or the host?

Comment: Ok, I did the thing number 2) and I realize the following:

Comment: When I call the first accordion, and then call the displayFb() function, the facecomm load perfect. Then, when I change to another accordion, **the facecomm still have it's content...the previous facebook comments thread**...so I tried then to call the displayFB function, and doesn't change the facecomm content....I tried then adding `$("#facecomm").empty();` on the accordion loader, but only is a solution to empty the facecomm but doesn't load the facecomm content of their respective id

Comment: Can you post the entire html or as the other commenter mentioned a cutdown example. Sounds like you are pushing the response into the wrong dom element.

Comment: I cant see any iframe on that html and I cant see any element with id="facecomm"

Comment: facecomm is created into loadAccordion function....I was talking about the iframe created by facebook comments...that's the way that facebook insert de comments...thank you.